# How to get parameters from GET request?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I can't retrieve the values from a request.

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String location_id = request.getReader().readLine(); // <---- null
    location_id = request.getParameter("location_id"); // <--- null
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(this.get_events_json(location_id));
}
```

On the client-side:

```
$.get("EventServe", {location_id : location_id}).done(function() {
    var events = JSON.parse(responseText);
    outer_this.events = events.map(function(event){
        var event = new Event(event.address, event.name, event.event_start, event.event_end)
        return event;
    });
    outer_this.events.map(function(event){outer_this.insert_event(event)});
});
```

I've also tried to pass it in directly without jQuery, using only literals.

Comment: Since I'm not completely sure how the parameters are passed to the server in this case, you could use [`request.getParameterMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) to retrieve all the parameters and seek for your desired parameter, then rewrite the code to use `request.getParameter` as you're already using.

Comment: This is a GET request so try printing out request.getQueryString() and see whether the parameter is a part of the Query String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$.get('EventServe', {location_id: location_id}, ...)` to make a HTTP `GET` request, you are passing the value of `location_id` as a query string parameter to the specified URL. Essentially you are requesting: `EventServe?location_id=4`, where 4 would be the value of `location_id`.

On the server side, you can access the query string parameters via [`getParameter(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public void doGet(...) {
    String locationId = request.getParameter("location_id");
}
```

A few extra notes:

- You should remove your call to `request.getReader().readLine()`. (Also, doesn't `readLine(byte[] b, int off, int len)` require arguments?)
- As a followup to the previous point, manually reading from the request via a `BufferedReader`, `InputStream`, or anything similar is a bad (used loosely) habit to get into, as doing so may interfere with `getParameter(String name)` in some cases:

> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` can interfere with the execution of this method.

[Source for the above quote.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

- Your client side code has a error where you define the function to run when the Ajax call is completed. The function should take `events` as an argument, as jQuery will automagically parse a JSON response:

  ```
  .done(function (events) {
      // Do things with the events
  });
  ```
- (*Puts on pedant hat.*) Your method name `get_events_json` does not follow Java conventions. Consider renaming it to `getEventsJson` or something to that effect.

Answer (score -1):

[Servlet Request Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)

Just look at `getAttribute(String name)` or `getParameter(String name)`.

Edit: `getParameter(String)` is for POST request, but you perform a GET request. Use `getAttribute(String)` instead

Comment: OP's already using `request.getParameter` but doesn't know the name of the parameter...

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that

Comment: And getAttribute won't help in any case.

Comment: `getParameter` works for any kind of request: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. `getAttribute` is meant to retrieve request attributes which **are not** request parameters...